# Git strange issue - forcing commit message during pull

Tags: git

There is something not setup correctly with my git repository but my lack of experience is stopping me from determining what it is.

I have a local development server which has no issues, but a remote test server which is running on develop constantly does the following after pulling:
"
`"Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by x commits"` where x is the number of commits that were just pulled in.

I have to end up deleting develop on the test server and then check it out again which stops that message.

Also if i pull in 2 commits and the say in 5 mins i pull in 2 more then the message changes to:

```
"Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 4 commits"
```

and it forces me to confirm the commit message each time also.

Whats wrong with this??

EDIT

I am also noticing something else strange.  Locally I have merged develop into master and then pushed master.  When I look at the log for develop it is showing as master being merged into develop??  But when i look at the branch locally it says "Merge branch 'develop'"

Comment: You need to explain how you are setting up the remote test repository, and also the exact commands you are using to pull.

Comment: Thats the problem, i am very new to git and have inherited this.  I am simply doing "git pull"

Comment: What does `git remote show origin` output?

Comment: You are not explaining how are you pulling: from where to where?

Comment: Hi i am logging on to the test server which is running on develop branch and doing a git pull directly on there.

Comment: You have still not answered my first question.  Please provide the *exact* commands you used to set up the test server, and also answer Emil's question, otherwise you are unlikely to get a useful answer.